# String constant inside aes in R - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

My query is with reference to this reprex:

```
d1 <- data.frame(index= 1:100,x=1:100,x_hat= 1:100+ rnorm(100))

ggplot(data = d1 ) + 
 geom_line(aes(x=index,y=x,color="True X")) +  
 geom_line(aes(x=index,y=x_hat,color="Estimated X")) + 
 scale_x_continuous(name = "" ) + 
 ylab("")
```

The code is doing what I want it to do but I don't know how it is doing it. When I say color = "True X"  I think it is generating a variable on the fly which is a constant.

Is that correct ? How is it working ? Can someone say a few words on this ? The beauty of this approach is that it automatically creates a correct legend.

Comment: I wrote a post that is closely related to this [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/legends-constants-for-aesthetics-in-ggplot2/), which you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is basically correct. Specifying a string constant within each `geom_line` is telling `ggplot2` to draw the line in a default color and add a legend labelled with whatever string you specified after `color =`. If you specified the same string in both geoms (e.g. `color = "True X"`), you would get only one line in that reddish default color to go along with a legend with only one label. So in other words, each unique string constant is telling ggplot to draw the respective line in a different color and add a label to the legend.

If you want to customize further, you can add `scale_color_manual` to your call to ggplot. For instance,  `scale_color_manual("Type of X", values = c("blue", "red"))` would add a proper title to the legend and change the colors of the two lines to whatever you want (in this case blue and red).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that your approach hacks around ggplots preference for tidy data. If you gathered your data to create a tidy data frame (e.g. via `d1 %>% gather(type.of.x, value, 2:3) -> d2`, you can avoid having to specify two separate calls to `geom_line` (like so: `ggplot(d2, aes(x=index, y = value, color = type.of.x)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual("Type of X", labels = c("Estimated X", "True X"), values = c("blue", "red"))`

Comment: So ggplot is generating the matrix ( which will be like the example of gather you have given )  to be plotted on the fly ?

Comment: No I don't think this is what happens. It simply plots your two specified layers separately and assigns default colors to the two strings you indicated in `color = `. You can (to an extent) assess what us going on internally by saving your ggplot object to the environment and investigate it using `View(yourggobject)`

Comment: Hi, I am able to see the data.frame built on the fly by using 

ggplot_build(ggplot(data = d1 ) + 
 geom_line(aes(x=index,y=x,color="True X")) +  
 geom_line(aes(x=index,y=x_hat,color="Estimated X")) + 
 scale_x_continuous(name = "" ) + 
 ylab(""))

Comment: That is a cool feature! Notice how there are two lists of data frame in this object, but when `gather()` is applied before hand there is only one. So, using your approach the plot is drawn from two separate dfs whereas when `gather()` was applied, one df suffices.